# Rusted kitchen basket strainer, mystery plumbing under the sink

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, p-trap

This is existing under my kitchen sink; the basket strainer was completely rusted.

The tailpiece looks different from any I've seen before and wasn't even tightened into the trap. It almost looks like it has a nut fused in. Once I removed the existing basket, I just lifted the tailpiece straight up from the trap and it slid out. I don't know if this whole assembly was missing a piece or what. The nuts around the trap won't bulge either and looks putty-ed in. Not sure if any of this is salvageable.

I went out and bought a new strainer with a long shank to match the existing one. I can't figure out how this thing was connected in the first place, it looks like the shank was just butting up against a totally disconnected pipe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://imgur.com/a/8qwRVbo

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm wondering how much of this assembly is still usable. Am I better off trying to get that fused p-trap off and buying a new (PVC) one? Or can I just replace the tailpiece and extender?

Comment: clean up all of the parts and see if they are damaged

Comment: It looks to me as though the bottom of your old strainer has completely rusted off and is now stuck in the nut at the top of the tail piece.

Answer (score 3):

There is no best approach here, I'm going to tell you what I would do in this situation.   I would try to replace as much as possible, back to the trap adapter, with a new plastic trap kit and a new plastic tail piece.  (To your comment: Not PVC.  Plastic drain tube.)

I'm not sure what's going on at the bottom of your existing tail piece.  It looks like the trap was used as a slip joint, even though it isn't one.  I'd want to get rid of that.  If the remaining metal parts are in similar condition to your tailpiece, I'd want to get rid of those too.

Regarding the remaining brass parts being stuck:  If they are really, really stuck I would call a plumber to dislodge them.  It takes some experience and finesse to remove them without damaging the in-wall plumbing, and I know there is a point where I might break things but an experienced plumber can get the job done.   You invest in a half-hour service call to avoid a full-day open-wall repair.

Comment: Polypropylene is likely the plastic (not PVC and not ABS) you're looking for, trap-parts-wise. I think the slip joint in the trap entry is there, missing its washer and corroded into immobility, not "not one" as such. I'd look to free up the nut and get a new washer, (since overall the trap looks fine, not too corroded) but different approaches are fine here...

Comment: That's a very long tailpiece; you may need to double up.